# Mysqli PHP Connection Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a connection from a web form to MySQL database using PHP. My code is as follows:

connection.php:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

if (!$link) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

phpinfo();
```

This part seems to work.. It then connects to thank you.php:

```
<?php

function connect()
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
    }

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);

require 'connection.php';
$conn    = Connect();
$query   = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT into Members (Username) VALUES('1111Username')");
$success = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);

}

echo "Thank You For Contacting Us <br>";

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

I am getting the following errors:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /var/sites/i/site/public_html/ContactForm/thankyou.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in /var/sites/i/site/public_html/ContactForm/thankyou.php on line 16

Comment: @Fred-ii- Is this a sentence that I should add to thank you.php?

Comment: I don't know why you're using 2 different files that contain 2 different connection calls. The simpler method would be to use 1 connection call and if you want to use that custom function `connect()` you will need to pass the connection variable to it, otherwise you'll have a problem with variable scope, which I believe is what's going on right now.

Comment: You also seem to have reposted the same from your other question earlier http://stackoverflow.com/q/43233031/1415724 - you should have edited it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your script:

1: You need to return the connection likes o:

```
function connect()
{
    return mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
}
```

2: When you run

```
$query   = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT into Members (Username) VALUES('1821Username')");
```

You have already executed the SQL to the DB, you do not need `$success = $conn->query($query);`

So your code should be:

```
<?php

function connect()
    {
        return mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
    }

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(~0);

require 'connection.php';
$conn    = connect();
$query   = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT into Members (Username) VALUES('1821Username')");

if (!$query) {
die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);

}

echo "Thank You For Contacting Us <br>";

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you SO much! That's it :)

Comment: @EmmaJ consider approving the answer if it helped you out and resolved your problem, so that it helps others who might face the same issue..

Comment: I will do! It's telling me to wait 8 minutes, so I'll do it as soon as I can! Once again, thank you!!

Comment: The function's called `connect()` here, but it's being called with a capital C. It's generally best to be sensitive to case.